# JSON.parse error when parsing XML inside JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Am using JSON.parse() method to parse a string, which contains XML structure inside JSON. So am getting the error as like JSON.parse.

Do you have any idea, how to use the XML inside the JSON?

Comment: Don't make us guess. Show that string.

Comment: XML can be present in legal JSON as a javascript string value.  Any further advice would need to see your JSON to see what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [base64](http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-base64.html) for data encoding, without losing data stability.